# When I print the multi-dimensional array, the arrays stacks up and up

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wanted to make a array which should be printed like this:

```
        [0] => 9
        [id] => 9
        [1] => Barcelona 
        [name] => Barcelona 
        [2] => voetbal
        [type] => voetbal
        [3] => 0
        [organisation_id] => 26
        [teams] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [tag] => 2
                        [2] => Barcelona 2
                        [naam] => Barcelona 2
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9

                        [0] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [tag] => 3
                        [2] => Barcelona 3
                        [naam] => Barcelona 3
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9
                        [0] => 9
                    )

        [id] => 10
        [1] => Real Madrid
        [name] => Real Madrid
        [2] => voetbal
        [type] => voetbal
        [3] => 0
        [organisation_id] => 27
        [teams] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [tag] => 2
                        [2] => Real Madrid 2
                        [naam] => Real Madrid 2
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 10

                        [0] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [tag] => 3
                        [2] => Real Madrid 3
                        [naam] => Real Madrid 3
                        [3] => 10
                        [club_id] => 10
                  )
```

But i'm getting this:

```
[0] => 9
        [id] => 9
        [1] => Barcelona 
        [name] => Barcelona 
        [2] => voetbal
        [type] => voetbal
        [3] => 0
        [organisation_id] => 26
        [teams] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [tag] => 2
                        [2] => Barcelona 2
                        [naam] => Barcelona 2
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9

                        [0] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [tag] => 3
                        [2] => Barcelona 3
                        [naam] => Barcelona 3
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9
                        [0] => 9
                    )

        [id] => 10
        [1] => Real Madrid
        [name] => Real Madrid
        [2] => voetbal
        [type] => voetbal
        [3] => 0
        [organisation_id] => 27
        [teams] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [tag] => 2
                        [2] => Barcelona 2
                        [naam] => Barcelona 2
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9

                        [0] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [tag] => 3
                        [2] => Barcelona 3
                        [naam] => Barcelona 3
                        [3] => 9
                        [club_id] => 9
                        [0] => 9

                        [0] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [tag] => 2
                        [2] => Real Madrid 2
                        [naam] => Real Madrid 2
                        [3] => 10
                        [club_id] => 10

                        [0] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [tag] => 3
                        [2] => Real Madrid 3
                        [naam] => Real Madrid 3
                        [3] => 10
                        [club_id] => 10
                  )
```

Here is my full code:

```
$resultaat_clubs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sportssite_clubs");

$clubs = array();
while($club = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat_clubs)) {
    $clubs[] = $club;
}


foreach($clubs as $index => $club) {

    $id = $club['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  eyeboxes WHERE location_id = $id");

    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
        unset($clubs[$index]);
    }
}
$teams = array();

foreach($clubs as $index => $club) {
    $id = $club['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  sportssite_teams WHERE club_id = $id");
    while($team = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // vul de teams array
        $teams[] = $team;
    }

    $clubs[$index]["teams"] = $teams;
}

print_r($clubs);
```

I don't want the answer but a hint or something, I'm learning more when someone gives a hint than the answer. But I couldn't find the error, I think there is something wrong with the seconds foreach loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you want only `Real Madrid` data, why not add that to the `WHERE` clause in your query?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I want to print everything in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the array `teams` outside the `for..each` loop. Thats why it is not clearing after one iteration. So put the array `teams` inside loop. Edit the code as follows:

```
foreach($clubs as $index => $club) {
    $teams = array();
    $id = $club['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  sportssite_teams WHERE club_id = $id");
    while($team = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // vul de teams array
        $teams[] = $team;
    }

    $clubs[$index]["teams"] = $teams;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `$teams = array();` inside `foreach` loop. ie.

```
foreach($clubs as $index => $club) {
    $teams = array(); // <-----
    $id = $club['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  sportssite_teams WHERE club_id = $id");
    while($team = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // vul de teams array
        $teams[] = $team;
    }

    $clubs[$index]["teams"] = $teams;
}
```